# .bat file changing first 3 letter of every filename to uppercase - Windows only

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-rename

From Filename : `1ab12345_def7890.txt`
to `1AB12345_def7890.txt`. Plese notice 1AB in uppercase.

I tried following but it is renaming whole file name to uppercase including extension.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd c:\some_dir

for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to isolate the leading three characters of filename first, perform your replacement, then prepend it back to the string.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

PushD "C:\some_dir" 2> NUL || GoTo :EOF

For %%G In (*) Do (Set "filename=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "leading=!filename:~,3!"
    For %%H In (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    ) Do Set "leading=!leading:%%H=%%H!"
    Ren "%%G" "!leading!!filename:~3!%%~xG" 1> NUL
    EndLocal)

PopD
```